# MySQL JOIN Not returning correct row set

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm having an issue with a join query which I am running. For some reason I am only getting 59,596 rows returned instead of 68,058.

I have tried various LEFT / RIGHT / INNER JOINS with no luck. I have double checked table CC and can confirm that there are 68,059 rows of data for the specified range. The derived table XX, however, has fewer rows.

I want to return all the rows from table CC despite if the row is in Table XX or not.

Below is the query I am using as well as the table structure:

```
    SELECT 

        CC.entity_code 'Entity Code 2'    

    ,       (SELECT MAX(action_date) AS secMaxDate 
            FROM 
            sys_reference.entities_visited DD

            WHERE 
            entity_code = XX.storeCode 
            AND     action_date < XX.maxDate) ' Previous Visit Date'
    ,       XX.maxDate  'Latest Visit Date'
    ,       cycle_end_date 'Cycle End Date'
    ,       WEEK(cycle_end_date,1)  'Cycle Week'
    ,   CASE 

            WHEN XX.visits > 10 THEN 0

            ELSE XX.visits

        END 'Total Visits (28 Days)'
    ,   CASE 
            WHEN XX.maxDate = MAX(CC.action_date) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS 'Call Cycle Compliance' 
    FROM 
        sys_reference.call_cycles CC
    LEFT JOIN        
        (SELECT 
            BB.entity_code AS storeCode
        ,   MAX(action_date) AS maxDate
        ,   MAX(cycle_end_date) AS cycle_end_date
        ,   (SELECT COUNT(AA.entity_code) FROM sys_reference.entities_visited AA WHERE AA.action_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31' AND AA.entity_code = BB.entity_code) AS visits
        FROM 
            sys_reference.entities_visited BB
GROUP BY 
            BB.entity_code
        ,   WEEK(BB.action_date,1)) AS XX        
    ON  
        CC.entity_code = XX.storeCode
    WHERE
        CC.action_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
    AND     YEARWEEK(cycle_end_date,1) BETWEEN YEARWEEK('2017-01-01') AND YEARWEEK('2017-01-31')
    GROUP BY 
        CC.entity_code
    ,   WEEK(cycle_end_date,1)
    LIMIT 0,100000;
```

Call Cycles Table

```
entity_code | action_date| cycle_end_date   
------------+------------+--------------- 
108792      |2017-01-07  |2017-01-11    
108792      |2017-01-10  |2017-01-11  
108792      |2017-01-12  |2017-01-18  
108793      |2017-01-08  |2017-01-11    
108795      |2017-01-06  |2017-01-11    
108796      |2017-01-05  |2017-01-11    
108795      |2017-01-13  |2017-01-18  
108792      |2017-01-07  |2017-01-11   
108792      |2017-01-14  |2017-01-18    
108793      |2017-01-14  |2017-01-18    
108796      |2017-01-16  |2017-01-18
```

Entities Visited Table

```
entity_code | visit_date | cycle_end_date   
------------+------------+--------------- 
108792      |2017-01-07  |2017-01-11    
108793      |2017-01-08  |2017-01-11    
108795      |2017-01-06  |2017-01-11    
108796      |2017-01-05  |2017-01-11    
108795      |2017-01-13  |2017-01-18    
108792      |2017-01-14  |2017-01-18    
108793      |2017-01-14  |2017-01-18    
108796      |2017-01-16  |2017-01-18
```

From the sample data, I need to return all rows from the Call Cycle Table.

Comment: Your sample data all fall out of your selection, perhaps you could pick a better sample set. Be aware that `BETWEEN` is inclusive on both sides, and for dates defaults  to midnight. That means that for example '2017-01-31 00:00:00' will be included in your set, but '2017-01-31 14:00:00' won't be. You also will need a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Apologies, this was an error on my side. The sample data should be within the date range specified. Let me update this. I have tried using a LEFT JOIN as per the update as well.

Comment: The issue seems because of the last GROUP BY. In the sample set there could be total >68000 rows but There may be only <60000 rows having unique combinations of CC.entity_code,WEEK(cycle_end_date,1). Try removing the last GROUP BY and check the count. That will help you further investigate.

Comment: Each entity code appears in the data set  4-5 times depending on the week in the month. I have also double checked this to see if this may be causing the issue with the GROUP BY, unless I am perhaps missing something?

Comment: Removing the last GROUP BY then leaves me with only one row.

Comment: Do you have any constraints on that particular table? your example doesn't has it

Comment: The Call Cycle Table is a monthly table which has rows added on  a monthly basis depending on entities that need to be visited.

The entities visited table table then collects data throughout the month as and when entities are visited. 

This means that the Call Cycle Table will always have all more if not exactly the same amount of rows.